# Hint or Text value is not getting removed from edittext when user is typing in edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I am having a edittext in my layout i have tried putting hint or text in my edittext.

When i touch or click edittext for first time the mobile keypad popups to type text, which is expected but the text or hint inside edittext is not getting removed. i have to tap 2 times the edittext then first time the mobile keyboard popups and second tap removes the text.

i want on first tap itself the text should get removed from edittext.

for example : Suppose if EditText is having initial text as ***User Name***, now when user click on edittext first time the ***User Name*** should get disappear so the user can type his name there.

below is my edittext code.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:hint="Enter Name..."
            android:textColor="#8c8c8c"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

Please help on above i have tried onClickListener also so that when we tap edittext it will make text empty but that also not working. i have to tap 2 times to remove text. i want the text should get disappear on first touch.

Comment: please share your java code also

Comment: use https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/ although your xml posted here looks fine

Answer (score 0):

Please check below points -

1. Check if you have set any text to EditText dynamically? If yes, you can remove it and set the text as hint. As you said, `if EditText is having initial text as User Name...` if you want to show text as hint or you need it to show only for the first time. Then, you set the required text `User Name` as hint NOT AS TEXT to editText.

You can use `editText.setHint("UserName")`  to set hint dynamically or `android:hint="UserName"` to set hint in xml.

If this is not the case, then you need to post the code snippets to find the exact error.

Comment: i am not setting Enter Name... in code i have just putted in android:hint="Enter Name..." in xml file as shown above. i want to remove Enter Name... when user click first time on text. even after i set in hint then also it is not removing on single click i have to tap 2 times.

Comment: Have you set text in that editText dynamically anywhere in your code? Since your xml code looks fine. This should not occur.

Comment: if i will put text in hint then first time when i will click in edittext cursor is coming at the end of ***Enter Name...*** and if i click again then it goes to start of edittext and then i can type in edittext.

Comment: when i click first time then cursor is coming at the end of ***Enter Name...*** so if i type something it is coming after ***Enter Name...*** but if i tap second time the cursor is going to start of edittext.

Comment: in my code i am just accessing value of edittext using ***EditText 
 name=findViewById(R.id.name);***

Comment: i have fixed the issue. issue was my android app was bringing it from cache i think i have uninstalled app and installed again fixed issue.